# MYSQL: Checking datafile being used from the command line

Tags: mysql, configuration, command-line

i am having trouble configuring mysql database to connect to the right file. I do not know which datafile is being used (due to some pretty tricky EC2 related moving around),

My question is: from the command line, how do i see what datafile is being used by the mysql database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the following:

```
mysqld --help --verbose | grep datadir
```